# WP MultiSite: Can't select database error after changing to new domain

Tags: multisite, database, mysql, sql

I've been developing a WP Multisite on a temp URL for some time now. The site is ready, so I changed my settings around, did a find and replace in SQL from the temp domain to the permanent domain, pointed my domain over.....

and now I get a "Can't Select Database" error.

I think part of the problem is my DB user is no longer being allowed to access the database anymore. When I went back into cPanel, I tried to connect my DB user to the database and this error came up.

> The system received an error from the “MySQL” database “mysql”: ER_NONEXISTING_GRANT (There is no such grant defined for user 'stack_db16' on host 'res154.servconfig.com')

Of course, mysql is not the actual DB name. It's something else.

So what is going on here? Totally confused and frustrated by this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Problem was I needed to update the wp_blogs table with the proper domain and path.

Answer (score 0):

That's a standard error if WordPress cannot connect to the database. Did you update the database details in the wp-config.php file?

I recommend double checking the DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, and DB_HOST values.